# Trailing comma removed by prettier

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have been using prettier and esLint for format and validation. when I add a comma in the interface, it will be removed by prettier and because of this I am getting esLint error.

```
  interface iMergeByItem{ 
    title?: string,
    meals: any
 }
```

Consider the above scenario, the comma getting removed when I format the doc, I have tried prettier **trailingComma** configuration but nothing works on the **interface** contents

Comment: Have you tried [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier)?

Comment: No, I will try this, thanks